# MYSQL query not returning all results

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a view table set up with the following fields:

> paymentID, jobID, jobNumber, jobType, countType, countID, salesRep, dealershipName, checkTS, paymentAmount, estimatedMailArrival

I need to select these fields when checkTS falls between a certain date range. (checkTS is a datetime field).  On top of these fields, I need to select two timestamps from another table named jobtasks (they may or may not exist, so I'll be using left joins).  To do this, I have set up the following query:

```
SELECT 
    s.jobID, s.jobNumber, s.jobType, s.countType, s.countID, s.salesRep,           s.dealershipName, s.checkTS, s.paymentID, s.paymentAmount, s.estimatedMailArrival, 
    jt1.completedTimestamp as Art, 
    jt2.completedTimestamp as List
FROM salesboard s
LEFT JOIN jobtasks jt1 ON s.jobID = jt1.jobID
LEFT JOIN jobtasks jt2 ON s.jobID = jt2.jobID
WHERE
    s.checkTS BETWEEN '2013-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-03-31 23:59:59' AND
    jt1.taskID = 22 AND
    jt2.taskID = 23
ORDER BY s.checkTS DESC;
```

The query doesn't return any errors, but I've found that it's not pulling all the records (it's pulling 182 of the 242 that should be pulled).  I can manually go into the database (mysql) and view records that should be pulled, but aren't.  One example - a timestamp of "2013-03-04 10:11:00" is not being pulled.

If i remove all the Art and List stuff, i get the correct number of results... 242.

```
SELECT 
    s.jobID, s.jobNumber, s.jobType, s.countType, s.countID, s.salesRep, s.dealershipName, s.checkTS, s.paymentID, s.paymentAmount, s.estimatedMailArrival
FROM salesboard s
WHERE
    s.checkTS BETWEEN '2013-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-03-31 23:59:59'
ORDER BY s.checkTS DESC;
```

Why would some records not be returned if i'm using a left join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `LEFT JOIN`, it doesn't do you any good to add fields from those tables to your `WHERE` criteria -- same as an `INNER JOIN` at that point.

I like to move those types of `WHERE` criteria to the `JOIN` itself:

```
SELECT 
    s.jobID, s.jobNumber, s.jobType, s.countType, s.countID, s.salesRep,           s.dealershipName, s.checkTS, s.paymentID, s.paymentAmount, s.estimatedMailArrival, 
    jt1.completedTimestamp as Art, 
    jt2.completedTimestamp as List
FROM salesboard s
LEFT JOIN jobtasks jt1 ON s.jobID = jt1.jobID 
    AND jt1.taskID = 22
LEFT JOIN jobtasks jt2 ON s.jobID = jt2.jobID
    AND jt2.taskID = 23
WHERE
    s.checkTS BETWEEN '2013-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-03-31 23:59:59' AND
ORDER BY s.checkTS DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
WHERE
    s.checkTS BETWEEN '2013-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-03-31 23:59:59' AND
    (jt1.taskID = 22 OR jt1.taskID IS NULL) AND
    (jt2.taskID = 23 OR jt2.tastID IS NULL)
```

Any `WHERE` conditions on `LEFT JOIN`ed tables are still counted (and the values of these columns will be `NULL` if the table isn't joined).

Comment: Nope, it's still returning 182 results :(

Comment: Can you show me the updated query in your question? Also, just in case, have you done `= NULL` instead of `IS NULL`? The `IS` is required.

Comment: I made only the changes you made - and yes, i did "IS" and not "=".  I'd show you in an edit, but sgeddes' response solved the issue.  Thanks for your input... nice to know about the tables still being counted.